# JS setTimeout not firing on onclick

Tags: javascript

I have been using this for a odometer on my site
http://github.hubspot.com/odometer/ , it is great but i can not seem to get it t o be able to work on a button onclick action.  it will only work when page is loaded.  i have tried to add to other functions like a simple window.alert the alert will work but it wont initiate the  setTimeOUt

here is my latest code:

```
<script>

function playSound() {

    setTimeout(function(){

    var audio = new Audio('sounds/machine-002-short.mp3');
    var audio2 = new Audio('sounds/coin-drop-4.mp3');

    audio.play();
    audio.volume = 0.65;
    audio.currentTime = 0.90;

    audio2.pause();
    audio.addEventListener("ended", function() {
    audio2.play();
    audio2.volume = 1.5;

        }); // event listener

    $('.odometer').html(<?php echo $Display;?>);
  }, 1000);  
} 
</script>
```

and the button:

```
<button id="submit" type="submit" type="button" name="roll" onclick="playSound();">Start</button>
```

if i just add a winow.alert it works just not with this set time out,  im very inexperienced in JS  so i am sure it is something simple

Comment: remove `type="submit"`  for sure

Comment: did you try `window.setTimeout`?

Comment: i removed  type="submit" and it worked  but that button is also part of a form i need to submit

Comment: @LuisEstevez that is unnecessary

Comment: then you need to submit the form in the setTimeout function in the playsound - it sounds more like you need AJAX to retrieve whatever the submit does

Comment: im not sure how to that could you assist me?  FYI that button is submitting info from a text box that i am posting to same page, and using that info to get the number to display in the odometer ..  so i put a number in- hit start and then it uses that info `$display`

Comment: Please see update to my question, It would be useful to see more of your HTML

Answer (score 1):

- a button can submit (type=submit - default) or not (type=button)
- If you need to submit the form, you cannot submit until after the setTimeout has run
- if the textarea is .odometer, use .val() instead of .html()
- Perhaps you do NOT want to submit the form, but instead AJAX in the content of the action. Like this:

```js
function getContent() {
  $.get($("#form1").prop("action", {data:$("#odometer").val()},function(data) {
     $('#odometer').val(data); // here we replace the $Display with what is returned
  });
}
function playSound() {

  setTimeout(function() {

    var audio = new Audio('sounds/machine-002-short.mp3');
    var audio2 = new Audio('sounds/coin-drop-4.mp3');

    audio.play();
    audio.volume = 0.65;
    audio.currentTime = 0.90;

    audio2.pause();
    audio.addEventListener("ended", function() {
      audio2.play();
      audio2.volume = 1.5;
      getContent();
    }); // event listener

    $('#odometer').val(<?php echo $Display;?>);
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" action="somefile.php">
  <textarea id="odometer"></textarea>
  <button type="button" id="but">Start</button>
</form>
```

Comment: that looks great,  my form is a bit more advanced that that i will edit above.   i wasnt 100% clear sorry...   the main function of the button is to submit this info to my database...  it triggering the odometer is secondary and like a progression/ countdown